# Two-Sample Rank Statistics

Tags: importance, ranks

Assume we got two models, either regression or RF or whatever. I'm trying to observe the relative importance of each feature by using ranks. That is, if we look at a regression model, we have a t-test (or z-test) for the hypothesis $\beta_j=0$ from which we can obtain p-values, then we can order the features according to their p-values. In RFs we've got Gini importance, you get the point.

Given that I have two ranking vectors (for the sake of simplicity, let's assume they both originate from regression models and relate to the same covariates), how can I compare them? Is there any known statistic?

Comment: Is the goal to compare the ranks of specific features (i.e., $rank_{featureA_{model1}}$ vs $rank_{featureA_{model2}}$) in either model to one another or the overall sequence features across both models (i.e., $(rank_{featureA}, rank_{featureB}, ...)_{model1})$ vs $(rank_{featureA}, rank_{featureB}, ...)_{model2})$)?

Comment: the overall sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at this question as one of trying to assess the reliability or agreement of the two models in terms of how they rate model features. A simple method for assessing agreement would be to compute the correlation (Pearson, Spearman, Kendall, etc.) between the two vectors of ranks.

The correlation coefficient between the two could provide a single value that would provide an assessment of their concordance.

Other agreement-oriented statistics such as [Krippendorf's $\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff%27s_alpha) could also be useful in this case as well but penalizes deviations across methods differently than would any of the correlation coefficients.  Give the linked Wikipedia page a look with attention to the difference function for ordinal data (most applicable to rank vectors like discussed here).

Comment: Thanks for this idea! Do you know of any approximations for the distribution of  Krippendorf's $\alpha$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any implementations of an approximation but have seen suggestions in the literature that there are parametric approaches to get a sampling variance for example in Hughes, J. (2021). krippendorffsalpha: An R Package for Measuring Agreement Using Krippendorff's Alpha Coefficient. R Journal, 13(1).